# QGIS - creating virtual layer from two layers

Tags: qgis

Scenario:
1 table layer (ET_ALKIS) - one of the columnnames "flstkennz"
1 polygon layer (IAN) - one of the columnnames "flstkennz"

Problem:
Table layer has too many entities to process, so i'd like to filter the rows with matching "flstkennz" values between Layer ET_ALKIS & IAN.

Question:
What SQL code would would be necessary to create a virtual layer?

Comment: That SQL query should be covered within the first lessons on w3.schools. Whether it is performancewise feasible I do not know.

Comment: As per the [Tour], please [Edit] your Question to ask One question.

Answer (score -1):

If your table and polygon are stored in PostgreSQL then you can just create a view that uses an inner join (ET_ALKIS<-->polygon). Once created, in QGIS, load your polygon and then join it to the view. Join your polygon using flstkennz and then ensure you only show records from your polygon that have a valid flstkennz value (i.e. not null). Any changes that occur (e.g. flstkennz values changed in the ET_ALKIS table, combining polygons in QGIS) would update the database and in turn update what you see in your polygon layer. You could also add a second copy of your polygon to QGIS that is unfiltered/unjoined for support and editing.

The definition of the view would be something like this:

```
SELECT e.data, e.flstkennz, p.data, p.flstkennz
FROM ET_ALLKIS e
INNER JOIN polys p ON e.flstkennz = p.flstkennz;
```